# Ionic 2/3 Pushing items in Array based on ID

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking to push items from one page to another, based on the category ID. Then I went to push all the contents from the array(who have the category ID that matches) to the next page.

I'm caught between using an if statement to pass the parameters to the second page, or to call the array in the second page and use an NgIf. Below is my code for a better visual. I'm fairly new to Ionic. Thank you for the help!

First Page

```
if(id = 1) {
    category_id: this.referenceList.category_id = 1;

    this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage,{category_id:"category_id"});
  }
  else {
    console.log("nope")
  }
```

Second Page

```
<div *ngfor = let reference of referenceList></div>
<div *ngif = category.id === 1> {{reference.referenceField1}} {{reference.referenceField2}} {{reference.media}} </div>
```

Not sure which one to use and why. Thanks again! Happy to clarify if there's any confusion.

Comment: do you know about `NavParams` on the receiving side? something like `this.navParams.get('xxx')` to retrieve the `category_id`.

Comment: is second page the html for the first page?

Comment: your ngIf,ngFor all are incorrect..

Comment: Add double or single quotes over ngIf and ngFor. Eg : *ngif = "category.id === 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored the `category_id` in a variable, so use this:

`this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage,{category_id:category_id});`

In the second page controller you need:

```
import ( NavParams ) from 'ionic-angular';

category_id: number;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    ...
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.category_id = this.navParams.get('category_id');
}
```

Also, your `html` should be (if I understand what you are doing):

```
<div *ngFor = let reference of referenceList>
    <div *ngIf = category_id === 1> 
        {{reference.referenceField1}};
        {{reference.referenceField2}};
        {{reference.media}}; 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: answered both my questions @ewizard - can't thank you enough!

Comment: :) just having some fun

Comment: Just one quick question for you @ewizard - whenever I type the <div *ngIf = category_id === 1>  , it doesn't register as a div and shows up as HTML text on screen. Wasn't sure if there was a new way to do it in ionic 3 or not.

Comment: you need `<div *ngIf = "category_id === 1">` with quotes...if u could mark my answer correct id appreciate it :)